# Using Lua functions with mplib and mpgraph

Tags: luatex, lua, luamplib

This question has reference to the question [Error with Lua, Luamplib and Mpgraph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/519690/error-with-lua-luamplib-and-mpgraph)
I am trying to use  lua functions inside mplib. The detailed code is here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\begin{luacode}
  require("math")
   local sin=math.sin;
\end{luacode}
\def\plot{%
  \directlua{
luamplib.process_mplibcode([[
    input graph ;
    beginfig(0)
    draw begingraph(5cm,3cm)
       gdraw (0,sin(0)) for x = 1 upto 3: .. (x, sin(x)) endfor ;
    endgraph ;
    endfig ;
  ]])}%
}
\plot
\end{document}
```

There seems some problem with intermingling of lua and mplib. Where would be the problem and how can this be corrected?

Comment: What makes you believe that statements within `luacode` will magically become available inside `process_mplibcode`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access Lua from within mplib using the `runscript` function.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\def\plot{%
  \directlua{luamplib.process_mplibcode([[
    vardef sin primary x =
        runscript("mp.print(math.sin(" & decimal x & "))")
    enddef ;
    input graph ;
    beginfig(0)
    draw begingraph(5cm,3cm)
       gdraw (0,sin(0)) for x = 1 upto 3: .. (x, sin(x)) endfor ;
    endgraph ;
    endfig ;
  ]])}%
}
\plot
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: BTW, if you just want to use `sin` it's probably shorter to just define `vardef sin primary x = sind(x*180/3.1415926) enddef;`

Comment: Is modification possible for standard expressions? For example \plot{sin(x)}, \plot{cos(x)+2} and in general \plot{f(x)} where f(x) is finite combination of some standard functions.

Comment: @user61681 Yes, that is possible.

Comment: Thanks for the update.