# How to draw graphs of standard functions using mpgraph?

Tags: plot, graphs, metapost, lua, luamplib

Is it possible to draw graph of standard functions using mpgraph (probably using lua, mplib)? For example something like gdraw(sin(x)+cos(x)), gdraw(2x+3) and in general gdraw(f(x)) where f(x) is finite combination of standard functions?

Comment: You should check out the Metafun XL format (from ConTeXt). It has graph drawing functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This questions seems to be a follow-up of [Using Lua functions with mplib and mpgraph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/519815/using-lua-functions-with-mplib-and-mpgraph)

You can simply construct the function that you want to plot from the macro parameter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\directlua{userdata = userdata or {}}
\begin{document}
\def\plot#1{%
  \directlua{
  function userdata.f(x)
      local _ENV = math
      return (#1)
  end
  luamplib.process_mplibcode([[
    vardef f primary x =
        runscript("mp.print(userdata.f(" & decimal x & "))")
    enddef ;
    input graph ;
    beginfig(0)
    draw begingraph(5cm,3cm)
       gdraw (0,f(0)) for x = 1 upto 1000: .. (x/100, f(x/100)) endfor ;
    endgraph ;
    endfig ;
  ]])}%
}

\plot{sin(x) + cos(x)}

\plot{sin(2*pi*x) * exp(-x/2)}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With a tiny bit of extra work you can also get keys and value to configure the plot.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
```

```lua
userdata = userdata or {}

userdata.mplibcode = [[
vardef f primary x =
    runscript("mp.print(userdata.f(" & decimal x & "))")
enddef ;
numeric xmin, xmax, samples, width ,height ;
xmin := runscript("mp.print(userdata.xmin)");
xmax := runscript("mp.print(userdata.xmax)");
samples := runscript("mp.print(userdata.samples)");
width := runscript("mp.print(userdata.width)");
height := runscript("mp.print(userdata.height)");
input graph ;
beginfig(0)
draw begingraph(width,height)
    gdraw (xmin,f(xmin)) for i = 1 upto samples:
        -- ((xmax - xmin) / samples * i + xmin, f((xmax - xmin) / samples * i + xmin))
    endfor ;
endgraph ;
endfig ;
]]

function userdata.graph(settings)
    settings = settings or {}
    userdata.xmin = tostring(settings.xmin or "0")
    userdata.xmax = tostring(settings.xmax or "1")
    userdata.samples = tostring(settings.samples or "100")
    userdata.width = tostring(settings.width or "5cm")
    userdata.height = tostring(settings.height or "3cm")
    luamplib.process_mplibcode(userdata.mplibcode)
end
```

```
\end{luacode*}

\newcommand\plot[2][]{%
  \directlua{
    local userdata = userdata
    local _ENV = math
    function userdata.f(x)
        return (#2)
    end
    userdata.graph({#1})
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\plot[xmin=-pi,xmax=pi,width="7cm"]{sin(x) + cos(x)}
%                            ^^^^^
%          need to be quoted because this is parsed by Lua

\plot[xmin=0,xmax=10,samples=1000]{sin(2*pi*x) * exp(-x/2)}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}

userdata = userdata or {}

userdata.mplibcode = [[
color clr ;
numeric Nf, rmin, rmax, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, samples, width ,height ;
Nf := runscript("mp.print(#userdata.f)");
rmin := runscript("mp.print(userdata.range[1])");
rmax := runscript("mp.print(userdata.range[2])");
xmin := runscript("mp.print(userdata.xmin)");
xmax := runscript("mp.print(userdata.xmax)");
ymin := runscript("mp.print(userdata.ymin)");
ymax := runscript("mp.print(userdata.ymax)");
samples := runscript("mp.print(userdata.samples)");
width := runscript("mp.print(userdata.width)");
height := runscript("mp.print(userdata.height)");

input graph ;

beginfig(0)
draw begingraph(width,height)
    setrange(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax) ;
    for n = 1 upto Nf:
        vardef f primary x =
            runscript("mp.print(userdata.f[" & decimal n & "](" & decimal x & "))")
        enddef ;

        clr := runscript("mp.print(userdata.color[" & decimal n & "] or 'black')") ;

        drawoptions(runscript("mp.print(userdata.style[" & decimal n & "] or '')")) ;
        gdraw (rmin,f(rmin)) for i = 1 upto samples:
            -- ((rmax - rmin) / samples * i + rmin, f((rmax - rmin) / samples * i + rmin))
        endfor withcolor clr ;
        drawoptions() ;
    endfor ;
endgraph ;
endfig ;
]]

function userdata.graph(settings)
    settings = settings or {}
    settings.range = settings.range or {}
    userdata.range = {
        tostring(settings.range[1] or "0"),
        tostring(settings.range[2] or "1")
    }
    userdata.xmin = tostring(settings.xmin or "0")
    userdata.xmax = tostring(settings.xmax or "1")
    userdata.ymin = tostring(settings.ymin or "whatever")
    userdata.ymax = tostring(settings.ymax or "whatever")
    userdata.samples = tostring(settings.samples or "100")
    userdata.width = tostring(settings.width or "5cm")
    userdata.height = tostring(settings.height or "3cm")
    userdata.color = settings.color or {}
    userdata.style = settings.style or {}
    luamplib.process_mplibcode(userdata.mplibcode)
end

\end{luacode*}

\newcommand\plot[2][]{%
  \directlua{userdata.f = {}}%
  \foreach \f [count=\i] in {#2} {%
    \directlua{
      local userdata = userdata
      local _ENV = math
      userdata.f[\i] = function(x)
          return (\f)
      end
    }%
  }%
  \directlua{
    local userdata = userdata
    local _ENV = math
    userdata.graph({#1})
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\plot[
    range={ 0, 10 },
    xmin=-1, xmax=11,
    ymin=-sqrt(2), ymax=sqrt(2),
    samples=1000,
    color={ "red", "blue", "(0,.8,.1)" },
    style={ "", "dashed evenly", "dashed withdots" }
]{sin(2*pi*x) * exp(-x/2), exp(-x/2), sin(2*pi*x)}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}

userdata = userdata or {}

userdata.mplibcode = [[
numeric Nf, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, width ,height ;
Nf := runscript("mp.print(#userdata.functions)");
xmin := runscript("mp.print(userdata.axis.xmin)");
xmax := runscript("mp.print(userdata.axis.xmax)");
ymin := runscript("mp.print(userdata.axis.ymin)");
ymax := runscript("mp.print(userdata.axis.ymax)");
width := runscript("mp.print(userdata.axis.width)");
height := runscript("mp.print(userdata.axis.height)");

input graph ;

beginfig(0)
draw begingraph(width,height)
    setrange(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax) ;
    for n = 1 upto Nf:
        vardef f primary x =
            runscript("mp.print(userdata.functions[" & decimal n & "].f(" & decimal x & "))")
        enddef ;
        numeric rmin, rmax, samples ;
        rmin := runscript("mp.print(userdata.functions[" & decimal n & "].range[1] or userdata.axis.range[1])");
        rmax := runscript("mp.print(userdata.functions[" & decimal n & "].range[2] or userdata.axis.range[2])");
        samples := runscript("mp.print(userdata.functions[" & decimal n & "].samples or userdata.axis.samples)");
        color clr ;
        clr := runscript("mp.print(userdata.functions[" & decimal n & "].color or userdata.axis.color)") ;

        drawoptions(runscript("mp.print(userdata.functions[" & decimal n & "].style or userdata.axis.style)")) ;
        gdraw (rmin,f(rmin)) for i = 1 upto samples:
            -- ((rmax - rmin) / samples * i + rmin, f((rmax - rmin) / samples * i + rmin))
        endfor withcolor clr ;
        drawoptions() ;
    endfor ;
endgraph ;
endfig ;
]]

function userdata.draw_graph()
    local axis = userdata.axis
    axis.range = {
        tostring(axis.range[1] or "0"),
        tostring(axis.range[2] or "1")
    }
    axis.xmin = tostring(axis.xmin or "whatever")
    axis.xmax = tostring(axis.xmax or "whatever")
    axis.ymin = tostring(axis.ymin or "whatever")
    axis.ymax = tostring(axis.ymax or "whatever")
    axis.samples = tostring(axis.samples or "100")
    axis.width = tostring(axis.width or "5cm")
    axis.height = tostring(axis.height or "3cm")
    axis.color = tostring(axis.color or "black")
    axis.style = tostring(axis.style or "")
    luamplib.process_mplibcode(userdata.mplibcode)
end

\end{luacode*}

\newenvironment{luamplibplots}[1][]%
  {\directlua{
       local userdata = userdata
       local _ENV = math
       userdata.functions = {}
       userdata.axis = {#1}
   }}%
  {\directlua{userdata.draw_graph()}}

\newcommand\addplot[2][]{%
  \directlua{
    local userdata = userdata
    local tableinsert = table.insert
    local _ENV = math
    tableinsert(userdata.functions, {
        f = function(x) return (#2) end,
        range = {},
        #1
    })
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{luamplibplots}
    [range={0,10},
     xmin=-1,
     xmax=11,
     ymin=-sqrt(2),
     ymax=sqrt(2),
     samples=1000]

    \addplot[color="red", samples=50]{sin(2*pi*x) * exp(-x/2)}
    \addplot[color="blue", style="dashed evenly"]{exp(-x/2)}
    \addplot[color="(0,.8,.1)", style="scaled 2pt dashed withdots"]{sin(2*pi*x)}
    \addplot[range={exp(-2),exp(2)}]{log(x)}

\end{luamplibplots}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for excellent help.

Comment: How can the option for ymin, ymax  and color of graphs can be added? Also is it possible to draw graphs of multiple functions in single figure?

Comment: @user61681 Nice challange.  I updated my answer but without further explanation.

Comment: Thank you for the wonderful solution. Sorry, but I didn't mean to challenge anything. Thanks again.

Comment: For some reason it is not supporting log(x).

Comment: @user61681 It should support log(x).  Keep in mind that log(x) diverges to -inf for x->0 and is undefined altogether for x<0.

Comment: @user61681 I've updated my answer yet again with a more flexible interface where you can set everything per function.

Comment: Thanks for all updates.

Comment: @user61681 Maybe I should actually package this up for CTAN.

Comment: Can we have some discussion prior to this? Would you please open for chat for this conversation?

Comment: @HenriMenke: The transparency interface is not clear from luamplib document. From the document it seems that transparency modes are implemented from context, but it doesn't give example of transparency user interface. Would you know how that could become one of the parameters here?

Comment: @HenriMenke As an example `gdraw (0,f(0)) for x = 1 upto 1000: .. (x/100, f(x/100))  endfor  withcolor transparent("normal",0.5,\mpcolor{myred})` or `gdraw (0,f(0)) for x = 1 upto 1000: .. (x/100, f(x/100))  endfor  withcolor transparent("normal",0.5,red)` edit to your first code block does not work; though this seems to work: `gdraw (0,f(0)) for x = 1 upto 1000: .. (x/100, f(x/100))  endfor  withcolor 0.5red;` (no transparency of course).

Comment: @reportaman MetaPost doesn't support transparency.  The `transparent` macro is from MetaFun and documented in the [MetaFun manual](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/metafun-p.pdf).  Also you should not use `transparent` but instead `withtransparency`.